# Let $n$ be a number $n>1 $.Find the general solution of the differential equation $y'+y=y^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $n$ be a number $n>1$ .Find the general solution of the differential equation $y'+y=y^n$

My attempt: $y'+y=y^n\rightarrow y^{-n}+y^{-n+1}=1$

Put $y^{-n}=t\rightarrow -ny^{n-1}y'=dt$ i cant go further

Comment: This is a "Bernoulli equation," which should be easily google-able.

Comment: for the theory see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly right. But
$$
y^{-n}y'+y^{1-n}=1
$$
suggests to take $u=y^{1-n}$, then $u'=(1-n)y^{-n}y'=(1-n)(1-u)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\int\frac{dy}{y^n-y}=\int dx.$$

The integral has a simple closed form.